# Enable EnableExternalImages property for a subreport (SSRS)

Tags: image, rdlc, subreport, ssrs-2012

I have a main report wich includes many sub reports. In eah sub report i have an image loaded externally. My main report is loaded fine but when i try to load a subreport i get an error saying that : EnableExternalImages property is not enabled in my sub report. 
My question is how to enable it? i can't acess to my sub report via code behind.
thanks.

Comment: This might help you https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5cf0977d-1972-42a1-9421-47bbfae7167d/nested-subreport-could-not-be-found?forum=vsreportcontrols

Comment: As far as I know there seems no solution on internet for this issue. If you found one post it here so it can be used in future by somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

When loading an image from a file location you need to specify "File:" in front of the absolute file path for the image *value* property.

```
="File:C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Jellyfish.jpg"
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: You have no idea how much this saved my life. Wolf needs to mark this as the answer!