# External images in protected folder will not show on subreport RDLC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, rdlc, subreport

I have several external images in a company directory that need to be shown in an RDLC report (with multiple subreports) and exported into a PDF. Thanks to [an answer by John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497975/enable-enableexternalimages-property-for-a-subreport-ssrs/31308822#31308822), external images now show up properly when testing from the server side, but **not** when loading from the live site. This is because of the Windows `Security` settings on the folder that these images are stored in.

Previously we would funnel data of images **that were stored in a SQL Server table** into a subreport through an `aspx.cs` file. Now that we've started storing images externally, the images needed to be handled like so:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getPicture] @key int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT picID,
           CONCAT( N'\\path\to\file\',
                   CONVERT(nvarchar(max), picID),
                   '.jpg'
                 ) AS [Picture]
    FROM tblImageData
    WHERE key = @key
END
```

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
    localReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
    localReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc");
    localReport.SubreportProcessing +=
        new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(subSupply);
    localReport.Refresh();
    …
    //Render the report
    renderedBytes = localReport.Render(…);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);
    Response.End();
}
public void subSupply(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
    int keyNumber = 1;
    sc.Open();
    DataSet dsSub = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("getPicture", sc);
    sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", keyNumber.ToString());
    sda.Fill(dsSub, "ds291");
    sc.Close();
    e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dtSub));
}
```

But without proper authentication, the images do not load correctly. There are currently other places on the website where images are loaded into a page by impersonating an authenticated user, but those do not need to load into an RDLC report -- and thus the images appear properly both on the server side and the client side.

I want to know if there is a way to get an authenticated user to pull image data when loading an RDLC subreport -- and to do this while the subreports' images are set to "external." My alternatives would be either to directly load all the images' bytes into the subreport through a separate `DataSet` **OR** to fetch the image data from the `getPicture` SQL procedure and funnel it back into the subreport. I have not had any luck with the former solution and the latter is something I *really* do not want to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may just have a permissions issue.  First use Windows File Explorer to see if you have access to the folder(s).  You need to be able to open files from the explorer before attempting with a c# application.  You will probably need an admin to help fix issue.  When yo use a double backslash \\path the path is a name of remote machine on the network.  So to have access to the remote folder you need permission on both the current machine and remote machine to access the file.  The remote machine may be a file server (or a shared folder on a remote machine) but it is still a machine.

Comment: @jdweng I must not have made it clear, but yes, the permissions issue is the root cause of the problem here, since the Windows security doesn't let just anyone in. I'm wanting to see if it's possible to get authentication to the folder while generating an RDLC report. I'm able to do this through impersonation on the C# side, but I've never done it while the PDF is loading.

Comment: if you are on a IIS machine users do not have access to the file system.  But you can use a Network driver.  Not sure if you are using a drive on a IIS or some other driver.  You also can create a role for the users.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs